# onStart, onRestart and onStop

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

Which life-cycle method will execute when I reopen the app ?

`onStart` executes when we view the app, `onStop` executes when we minimize it, Will the `onStart` method executes again if maximize it?

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: Create new app with All the lifecycle method. Put Log in every method . And try yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When you re open the app. OnResume method will be called. See here [image]

[Image Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 1):

How about checking it yourself. This can be a good exercise as well. Override all these methods and put individual logs in each of them so you can identify for e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("Activity TAG","On Resume");
}
```

Check the logcat output and verify this for yourself. Hope it helps.

Comment: Good approach!
I've learned about the lifecycle and perfectly synced it with that one of the SurfaceView. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since @Mohit Patel mentioned in his comment and posted a photo about it, combined with the @Karan Mer answer, your answer is: Yes, the onStart method executes again if maximize it.

You can prove it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("Activity TAG","On Resume");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("Activity TAG","On start");
}
```

The lifecycle is the ABC of Android. You should be careful with it. This is the activity lifecycle:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/images/activity_lifecycle.png

or if you are using fragments:

https://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png